# django queryset aggregation count counting wrong thing

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

This is a continuation question from:
[Django queryset get distinct column values with respect to other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905220/django-queryset-get-distinct-column-values-with-respect-to-other-column)

**My Problem:**

Using aggregate count in Django counts the wrong thing in the queryset, or as far as I can see something that is not even in my queryset.

**What I did**
I used:

```
queryset.order_by('col1', 'col2').distinct('col1', 'col2').values('col2')
```

to get the values of `col2` of a model where all the rows have a distinct pair of values in `(col1, col2)`. There is an example in the link above. I printed my queryset and it looks good, I have

```
[{'col2': value1}, ... , {'col2': value1},{'col2': value2}, ..., {'col2': value2},...]
```

I now want to count how much each value appears in the queryset I got. I do this using aggregation count. I have:

```
a = {'count': Count(F(col2), distinct=False)}
queryset.annotate(**a)
```

I tried this with ``distinct=True` as well but no luck

I would expect to get `[{col2:value1, count: num1}, {col2:value2, count: num2} ...]`.
Instead I get `[{col2: value1, count: num11}, {col2: value1, count: num12}, ... ,{col2: value1, count: num_1n}, {col2: value2, count: num21}, ... ,{col2: value1, count: num_2n}, ...]`.
Where as far as I can tell num11, ...., num_1n are the amount of lines value1 existed in col2 with any specific value in col1, previous to me using `order_by('col1', 'col2').distinct('col1', 'col2').values('col2')` when preparing the query.

I can't figure out what can cause this. I tried looking in the `queryset.query` parameter but I can't understand where I am going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't you `Count(F('col1'))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.order_by` should specify only `'col2'`, like:

```
queryset.values('col2').annotate(
    count=Count('col1', distinct=True)
).order_by('col2')
```

This will thus yield a `QuerySet` that looks like:

```
< QuerySet [
    {'col2': 1, 'count': 4 },
    {'col2': 2, 'count': 2 }
]>
```

So that means that there are four *distinct* values for `col1` given `col2` has value `1`, and two distinct values for `col1` given `col2` has value `2`.

This will construct a query like:

```
SELECT col2, COUNT(DISTINCT col1) AS count
FROM some_table
GROUP BY col2
ORDER BY col2
```

The `.distinct(..)` is here not *necessary* since due to the `GROUP BY` we will only obtain distinct `col2` values, and because we `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` this thus means that each *distinct* value of `col1` is counted once.